# Encrypted comunication between C# and PHP without SSL - certificate?

Tags: c#, php, ssl, certificate, encryption

I need an encrypted communication between C# and PHP to send HttpWebRequest's and download files from the server. Is that possible without buying a certificate for https? I think a certificate should'nt be needed in my case, isn't it? What do you recommend to use?

Comment: You don't need to **buy** certificate if you only planning to use it between known server - just make it trusted on client end (or even manually verify one)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I thought a certificate is needed in every case. But I just read that I need to install for example OpenSSL on the server to use ssl-communication. Is there a way to do it without installing something, just with php stuff?

Comment: Yes you need certificate for HTTPS, but you can create one yourself because you don't need other users to trust it (like you would need for normal site - random users will not trust your self-signed certificate even if it have valid subject name for your site). I have no idea how to configure PHP server for SSL... In IIS it is trivial (part of adding binding).

Answer (score 0):

If you control both ends, you can generate your own certificate and manually check that the server is using the expected one.  It's in the case where the client wants to *verify* that the server is using the correct certificate that you need the functionality provided by a certificate authority.

Normally, the certificate is loaded into the web server and the encryption/decryption is invisible to any code running on the server.  I would be very surprised if you could do it with just "php stuff".